# how to combine Spring webserviceTemplate with @RequestWrapper infos?

Tags: java, spring, web-services, soap

To enable easy testing of my SOAP client (by leveraging on MockWebServiceServer), I want to use Spring's webserviceTemplate.

SOAP endpoint is a .Net server . Based on the wsdl, I'm able to generate the beans (mainly a Request class) and endpoint interface.

The generated interface is below :

```
@WebService(targetNamespace = "http://Microsoft.ServiceModel.Samples", name = "IWcfRed")
@XmlSeeAlso({ObjectFactory.class, com.microsoft.schemas._2003._10.serialization.ObjectFactory.class})
public interface IWcfRed {

    @WebResult(name = "CallCheckXmlResult", targetNamespace = "http://Microsoft.ServiceModel.Samples")
    @Action(input = "http://Microsoft.ServiceModel.Samples/IWcfRed/CallCheckXml", output = "http://Microsoft.ServiceModel.Samples/IWcfRed/CallCheckXmlResponse")
    @RequestWrapper(localName = "CallCheckXml", targetNamespace = "http://Microsoft.ServiceModel.Samples", className = "samples.servicemodel.microsoft.CallCheckXml")
    @WebMethod(operationName = "CallCheckXml", action = "http://Microsoft.ServiceModel.Samples/IWcfRed/CallCheckXml")
    @ResponseWrapper(localName = "CallCheckXmlResponse", targetNamespace = "http://Microsoft.ServiceModel.Samples", className = "samples.servicemodel.microsoft.CallCheckXmlResponse")
    public java.lang.String callCheckXml(
        @WebParam(name = "xmlRequest", targetNamespace = "http://Microsoft.ServiceModel.Samples")
        java.lang.String xmlRequest
    );
}
```

my webserviceTemplate is properly configured (I think) with marshaller and messageFactory and defaultUri, to send something.

So when I call the code below

```
Request myRequest=generateDummyRequest();
webServiceTemplate.marshalSendAndReceive(myRequest,new SoapActionCallback ("http://Microsoft.ServiceModel.Samples/IWcfRed/CallCheckXml"));
```

myRequest gets marshalled into XML, and I can see the body of the request starts with `<Request>` tag.

I thought that would be good and enough, but I get a very clear error message from server :

> org.springframework.ws.soap.client.SoapFaultClientException: Error in
>   deserializing body of request message for operation 'CallCheckXml'.
>   OperationFormatter encountered an invalid Message body. Expected to
>   find node type 'Element' with name 'CallCheckXml' and namespace
>   'http://Microsoft.ServiceModel.Samples'. Found node type 'Element'
>   with name 'Request' and namespace ''

So my Request should be wrapped in a CallCheckXml element, fair enough. And I understand this is actually defined in the generated interface with the infos in the @RequestWrapper annotation, so it kind of makes sense.

But how do I get Spring to do this nicely for me ? Do I need to do it myself in a [WebServiceMessageCallback](http://docs.spring.io/spring-ws/site/apidocs/org/springframework/ws/client/core/WebServiceMessageCallback.html) ? or should I forget webservicetemplate and move to [JaxWsPortProxyFactoryBean](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/remoting/jaxws/JaxWsPortProxyFactoryBean.html) ?

None of these 2 solutions seem very appealing to me. And if webserviceTemplate is Spring standard for SOAP operations, my guess is rather that I'm missing something here.

Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the SOAP modelization done by the team in charge of the server is really sub-optimal (to stay polite) ; Actually I could have guessed with the default "Microsoft" namespaces used, directly taken from a sample example, and not adapted to our context.

The wrapper class is actually getting generated, and I didn't notice it before. So I instanciate the wrapper class through the ObjectFactory, but because that wrapper doesn't even accept the domain object as an attribute, I first have to marshall the domain object myself into a JAXBElement , then set the result on the wrapper. Finally, the marshaller configured in Spring will kick in, and marshall the wrapper class into proper query.

Same gymnastic I have to do with the response, going through a double unmarshalling...

So I guess the real answer is to have a proper SOAP modelization in place.